# How can i limit the post view for unauthenticated user in class based view django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. In my project I want to make home page which views some of the post.But if user get registered or authenticated then they can view all the post available on the website. so far I have created the view which renders all the post on home page but I want to limit them.

I am using class based view.

> posts/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/post_detail.html'
```

> posts/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from slugger import AutoSlugField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.slug, filename)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 60)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True ,related_name='children',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_location,
        null=True, 
        blank=True,
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Comment: Please share your relevant model(s) and views.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem have a look i have added posts/view and posts/models

Comment: So you only want to show `Post`s for which the logged in user is the `author`?

Comment: no user can't create posts. actually i want to make view some of the posts on home page. but when user registers then they can view all the posts

Comment: and in case the user is not logged in, then what should happen?

Comment: i don't want my home page to show login or register form. login and register buttons are available on the navbar.

Comment: in case if user is not login they can only see the home page which renders some of the latest posts.

Answer (score 2):

In a `ListView`, the default QuerySet is all objects. In your case, with the `model` set to `Post`, the default queryset is `Post.objects.all()`.

You can override the `get_queryset()` method of the `ListView`. Check out [this website](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) to get a good understanding of Django CBVs.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        return qs
    else:
        return qs.filter(<add a filter for not logged in users>)
        # of return qs[:10] # to limit to 10 posts
```

Answer (score 2):

## Redirecting the user

You can use the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) to prevent users to see a view if they are not logged in. In that case the default behavior is to redirect to the login page.

You can add the mixin to your views like:

```
# posts/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']


class PostDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/post_detail.html'
```

The documentation describes that you can set the `redirect_to` class attribute to something else if you want to redirect the user to another page.

## Show a page without `Post`s (or filter these)

You can also decide to render the page, but without any `Post` objects. We can handle that by patching the `get_queryset` method:

```
# posts/views.py

from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Post.objects.none()
        else:
            return super().get_queryset()


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/post_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Post.objects.none()
        else:
            return super().get_queryset()
```

Comment: It show login form on the homepage i dont want that. I want somthing else to display on home page. I want some contents over there.

Comment: @adityakumar: then you should go with option 2, or redirect to another page of interest. I forgot to remove the `LoginRequired` in the second option.

Comment: should i use this      if not self.request.is_authenticated: return redirect('posts/home.html')

Comment: @adityakumar: no, you just return a queryset of `Post` objects you would like to display, in this case, we use `.none()` (so no `Post` objects at all), or you can patch `get_template_names` and thus return another template in that case.

Comment: i did this return Post.objects.filter(Post[:10]) now it says 'super' object has no attribute 'get_queyset'

Comment: @adityakumar: well it should be `Post.objects.all()[:10]` I guess. Is this, by ancy chance Python-2.x?

Comment: it still says   'super' object has no attribute 'get_queyset'

Comment: @adityakumar: of course it says that, since your `Post.objects...` call, although incorrect, was never performed. The question remains: are you using Python-2.x? Did you subclass from `ListView` and/or `DetailView`?

Comment: I am using  python 3.7

Comment: @adityakumar: looks like you made a typo: it is `get_queryset`, not `get_queyset`.

Comment: yeah i am sorry that was a typo.And thank you for help.

Comment: in postDetail part it gives me error  "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken". where this is coming from ?

Comment: @adityakumar: well that is indeed correct, since the `DetailView`, performs extra filtering: it filters such that it retrieves the `id`, but if you first slice, then that makes no longer sense, so I think for a detail view, using slicing makes no sense.